# C struct array assignment problems

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm new to C and I am working with a struct array. I'm having trouble assigning values to it. here is my struct..

```
struct student{
        char firstname[30];
        char surname[30];
        int streetNo;
        char streetName[30];
        char suburb[30];
        char state[4];
        int postCode;
        char DOB[10];
        int studentNo;
        char gender;
        char courseNo[4];
        char active;
        int WAM;
    };
struct student person[1000];
```

here is me assigning a value to the struct

```
person[100].firstname = "dan";
```

and this is my error

```
 assignment type mismatch: array[30] of char "=" pointer to char
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, a string like this is implemented using a character array. A character array is exactly what you have defined, but it is not possible to assign a string directly like this in C. You will have to use string functions for that. The function to use is `strcpy()`. You have to assign like:-

```
strcpy(person[100].firstname, "dan");
```

Comment: thank you that worked great! i totally forgot about strcpy ahahahaha

Answer (score 4):

Although you can *initialize* an array of characters from a string literal like this

```
char str[] = "dan";
```

you cannot *assign* a string literal to an array of characters the way you are trying to do.

You need to *copy* your string into the character array using one of the string copy functions:

```
strcpy(person[100].firstname, "dan");
```

If yo would like to copy `"dan"` into the first four elements and pad the remaining elements of `firstname` with zeros, use `strncpy`:

```
strncpy(person[100].firstname, "dan", 30);
```

It is worth pointing out that you could make `firstname` a pointer, and either allocate memory for your strings dynamically, or assign it directly:

```
 struct student{
    char *firstname;
    char *surname;
    /* and so on... */
 };

 student[100].firstname = "dan";
 student[100].surname = "brown";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can only initialize array like that at the time of declaration only, else you need to use

```
strcpy(person[100].firstname,"dan");
```

you can't even do like that with a simple char array

```
char a[30];
a="dan";
```

the complier will tell :

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[30]’ from type ‘char *’
```

because "dan" is a string literal that is being held by a pointer which can't be assigned like this to an array.

Comment: You can also go like this...

    `struct student
    {
        char *firstName;
    }person[100];
    person[30].firstName = "dan";'

Comment: Not good. This will run into major problems as soon as you try to change `student.firstname`.

Comment: *You can only initialize array like that at the time of declaration only* - Nice catch!

Answer (score 3):

**Arrays are not pointers**, and this is one example of it.
Arrays cannot be assigned to, only array *elements* can be assigned to.
You could do

```
 person[100].firstname[0] = 'd';
 person[100].firstname[1] = 'a';
 person[100].firstname[2] = 'n';
 person[100].firstname[3] = '\0'; /* Pretty tedious... */
```

or, if you know that you don't copy more than 30 bytes,

```
 strcpy (person[100].firstname, "dan");
```

Answer (score 1):

An array name itself gives array base address.. And an array base address cannot be a left side value.

```
  person[100].firstname  =
```

gives you error since you are assigning some other value to array base address which is not allowed.

You can initialize

```
char stringArray[]  = "some string";
```

but you can't assign value to already declared array

```
  char stringArray[100];
  stringArray     =   "some string";  <== error
```

You alternative is to use strcpy

```
 strcpy(stringArray, "sometext");
```

Answer (score 1):

The specific problem is that you are attempting to assign a string to an array of bytes.

What you need to do in that particular case is to copy the contents of the string you want into the array, like so:

```
strncpy(person[100].firstname, "dan", 30);
```

A more general problem is what you are doing is terrible. For student records like this, the only sensible thing to do is to use a proper database; in your case using [SQLite](http://sqlite.org) is probably appropriate. Using a database for a simple learning exercise like so might seem like overkill, but it is experience that'll help you out a lot later.

Answer (score 1):

You can `strcpy()` for assigning value to char array.

```
strcpy(person[100].firstname,"Dan");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign like this to an array. Even without a struct. That is

```
char name[10];
name = "ert";
```

is an error.

(You can do it only in initialization `char name[10] = "ert";`)

The correct way to do it is

```
strcpy(person[100].firstname, "dan");
```

Safer to use a variation of `strcpy` that requires a max size of string.